# How do I reference a promise returned from a chained function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, protractor

I'm new to promises, and I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly. I'm trying to make a calculation with some promises, so I chained a bunch of functions together.  First I wrote it like the following, which worked, but doesn't seem like good code.

```
it('should verify CPC column', function() {
  ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('aggRow')).then(function(promCells) {
    getAggCellColumn('CPC').then(function(promColCPC) {
      getAggCellColumn('Spend').then(function(promColSpend) {
        getAggCellColumn('Clicks').then(function(promColClicks) {
          promCells[promColCPC].getText().then(function(promStringCPC) {
            promCells[promColSpend].getText().then(function(promStringSpend) {
              promCells[promColClicks].getText().then(function(promStringClicks) {
                var floatCPC = parseFloat(promStringCPC);
                var floatSpend = parseFloat(promStringSpend);
                var floatClicks = parseFloat(promStringClicks);
                var result = Math.round((floatSpend / floatClicks) * 100) / 100;
                expect(floatCPC).toEqual(result);
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I researched promises some more and came up with the following:

```
it('should verify CPC column', function() {
  ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('aggRow'))
    .then(getAggCellColumn('CPC')) 
    .then(getAggCellColumn('Spend')) 
    .then(getAggCellColumn('Clicks')) 
    .then(promCells[promColCPC + 2].getText()) 
    .then(promCells[promColSpend + 2].getText()) 
    .then(promCells[promColClicks + 2].getText()) 
    .then(function(promStringClicks) {
      var floatCPC = parseFloat(promStringCPC);
      var floatSpend = parseFloat(promStringSpend);
      var floatClicks = parseFloat(promStringClicks);
      var result = Math.round((floatSpend / floatClicks) * 100) / 100;
      expect(floatCPC).toEqual(result);
    });
});
```

This doesn't work, but I'm trying to get the result of findElements to be promCells.  I also would like to reference the results from the getText() functions. Please let me know if I should be approaching this problem differently. Thanks!

I was also thinking about writing it like this...

```
it('should verify CPC column', function() {
  ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('aggRow'))
    .then(function(promStringClicks) {
      var floatCPC = parseFloat(promCells[getAggCellColumn('CPC') + 2].getText());
      var floatSpend = parseFloat(promCells[getAggCellColumn('Spend') + 2].getText());
      var floatClicks = parseFloat(promCells[getAggCellColumn('Clicks') + 2].getText());
      var result = Math.round((floatSpend / floatClicks) * 100) / 100;
      expect(floatCPC).toEqual(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are `getAggCellColumn` and `getText` asynchronous or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises concept in JS is function chaining, with error handling. In your case, you're okay with chaining only.

So in order to chain your calls, you must pass **functions**, that can return some value to be used by the next function of the chain.

Note that in unit testing, the `it`s have to know when your chain ends, so you can expect the `done` function and call it when your chain has finished.

You finally would have something like:

```
it('should verify CPC column', function(done) {
    var promStringCPC, promStringSpend, promStringClicks;
    ptor.findElements(protractor.By.className('aggRow'))
        .then(function (promCells) {
            // Do something from async result like the following...
            promStringCPC = promCells.getAggCellColumn('CPC');
            promStringSpend = promCells.getAggCellColumn('Spend');
            promStringClicks = promCells.getAggCellColumn('Clicks');

            var floatCPC = parseFloat(promStringCPC);
            var floatSpend = parseFloat(promStringSpend);
            var floatClicks = parseFloat(promStringClicks);
            var result = Math.round((floatSpend / floatClicks) * 100) / 100;
            expect(floatCPC).toEqual(result);

            // You can do async additional stuff here...
            // return asyncResultOrNestedPromise
        }) 
        .then(function (result) {
            // ... and use the async's result here
        })
        .then(done);
});
```

Note that I didn't clearly get your specific case. Anyway I'm trying to make you understand the promises concept!

Comment: Thanks a lot blint, that was really helpful and I understand it better now.