# How to structure Protractor promises

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

In this example I'm testing whether an element is located at the bottom of the page. I'm using the promises in Protractor/Webdriver, but I think I'm using it wrong because I don't think it's supposed to look this messy.

```
describe('Element', function(){
    it('should be placed at bottom', function(){
        element(by.id('page').getSize().then(function(dimP){
            element(by.id('element').getLocation().then(function(locE){
                element(by.id('element').getSize().then(function(dimE){
                    expect(locE.y + dimE.height).toEqual(dimP.height);
                })
            });
        });
    })
});
```

How can I do this in a cleaner way? I'm using Protractor version 2.1.0.

I have tried to do like this:

```
expect(element(by.id('page').getSize().height).toEqual(1000);
```

But it says *Expected undefined to equal 1000.* So it seems like I can't use return values as explained here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md

(I am using a page object in my actual test, so the variables are not as ugly as in the example.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `getSize()` and `getLocation()` both return promises and you need actual values, you have to resolve all of the promises, either explicitly with `then()`, or let `expect()` implicitly do this for you.

I'm actually understanding your question as *"How to flatten a promise chain in Protractor?"*. This is there `promise.all()` would help to resolve multiple promises at once which would save you from writing multiple nested `then()` callbacks:

```
var elm = element(by.id('element')),
    page = element(by.id('page'));

var promises = [elm.getSize(), elm.getLocation(), page.getSize()];

protractor.promise.all(promises).then(function (values) {
    expect(values[0].height + values[1].y).toEqual(values[2].height);
});
```

See also:

- [Flattening Promise Chains](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/)
- [How do I reference a promise returned from a chained function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864843/how-do-i-reference-a-promise-returned-from-a-chained-function)
- [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Comment: How can I make expect() resolve the promise? Am I doing something wrong in the second code block, since it resolves to _undefined_? The promise.all() seem like a good solution.

Comment: @KMK implicitly resolving promises with expect is something I've mentioned, but is not needed here. And, unfortunately, you cannot get a property value from a not yet resolved promise like `element(by.id('page')).getSize().height`. Basically, from what I understand, your question is about flattening a promise chain. I'll update the answer with some more information. Stay tuned. Thanks!